# Stop Django from autofilling manytomany fields in admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, many-to-many

I have the following models:

```
class Color(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
            return self.name

class Flower(models.Model):
    flower_number = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
         default=1,blank=True, null=True)
    petal_color = models.ManyToManyField(Color,blank=True, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_petal",
        related_query_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s")
    petal_outer_color = models.ManyToManyField(Color,blank=True, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_petal_outer",
        related_query_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s")
    class Meta:
         abstract = True

class Plant(Flower):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
```

On the Admin I just have:

```
admin.site.register(Plant)
```

When I go into the Django admin and fill out either of the manytomany `petal_color` or `petal_outer_color` with data the other manytomany field automatically gets filled when it saves. How do I stop this from happening? Nothing shows up as an error and I tried going back and deleting and re-entering data but it still happens

Comment: both fields `related_query_name` is same and also point to same model. Can you try with identical query-name , i mean different query-name. Actually there is no need to add that. Just remove this.

Comment: @Shakil yep this worked Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using symmetrical=False in the ManyToManyField, that might be causing the issue here as you have two M2M fields going to the same model.
Read up on symmetrical in the Django docs.

Do something like this

```
class Flower(models.Model):
    flower_number = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
         default=1,blank=True, null=True)
    petal_color = models.ManyToManyField(Color,blank=True, symmetrical=False related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_petal",
        related_query_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s")
    petal_outer_color = models.ManyToManyField(Color,blank=True, symmetrical=False, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_petal_outer",
        related_query_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s")
    class Meta:
         abstract = True
```

By default, the value of symmetrical is True for Many to Many Field which is a bi-directional relationship.
The ManyToManyField is assumed to be symmetrical – that is, if I am your friend, then you are my friend.

Comment: You should try naming your related_query_name differently, as they refer to the same model, that might be causing an issue.